# insert google analytics code in javascript file

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking

Maybe this Duplicate : [google analytics in JS file instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689518/google-analytics-in-js-file-instead)

I tried to add the code of Google's statistics to JS file And I could not do it.

I tried 3 ways

1.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += "<script>(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {(i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)}, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');ga('create', 'UA-48139516-1', 'accessbar.co.il');ga('send', 'pageview');</script>";
```

2.
Insert the code to function and call the function on "window.onload".

```
function googleAna() {
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-48139516-1', 'accessbar.co.il');
ga('send', 'pageview');
}
```

3. Enter the code as is to the JS file And let it load while reading the JS file

In all cases, Google did not recognize I put the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put the code into another Javascript file.  When you add the javascript file to the page its going to be the same as if you had added it to the main file.

How do you know it didn't work? Did you check the real-time reports that should show something right away. The standard reports can take up to 24 hours before you start to see data.

---

```
<script>(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {(i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)}, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
   ga('create', 'UA-48139516-1', 'accessbar.co.il');
   ga('send', 'pageview');</script>
```

If you copy that exactly as it is and place it in the  section of your website.  It should start logging.    I think maybe you for got the  in your version nr2.

Comment: i check the real-time reports And it says that no site visits. Which method is best from What I tried or maybe there is a better way? I do not have to put the code in another file It does not work at all When i put the code in JS file, It only works in HTML file.

Comment: the easiest way to do it is to just copy the code from the GA site and paste it some where on the page with in a <script type='text/javascript'></script> tag.  Best place would probably be in the head tag. But it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score -1):

you copy the file and then paste it to google then type html:// then your command...then that should execute the command. An example command is, html://installJS/delete blocks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This doesn't seem to really address the question that is being asked here. The question is asking about how to add the Google Analytics code in a JS file, not how to execute it in a browser, which is what I think you're suggesting here.